# c# - Total of all rows within a specific column

Tags: c#, datatable

I need some help here. Can't seem to get a way around this. Basically I have a datatable with a number of rows, and I need to get the total of all the rows for a specific column. The column I am trying to get includes a set of numbers. I need to add each of these together but it is not determined how many rows will be present. I have a dataset with 3 tables inside it, and i need to do this for the third table. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you got any code samples of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by the following code

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int Sum = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dRow in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
        {
            Sum += Convert.ToInt32(dRow["Required Column"]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of  [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx)

```
private void ComputeBySalesSalesID(DataSet dataSet)
{
    // Presumes a DataTable named "Orders" that has a column named "Total."
    DataTable table;
    table = dataSet.Tables["Orders"];
    var sumObject = table.Compute("Sum(Total)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable table = yourDataSet.Tables[2];

double sumObject = (double)(table.Compute("Sum(YourSpecificColumnName)"));
```